# How can I autoselect free shipping?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping

If the costumer can get free shipping, it should be autoselected. Is there an easy way to do it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This solution will select the shipping method when there is only one present. It doesn't look for free shipping or another one... Just the single one present.

```
OPEN
app/design/frontend/<your package>/<your theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
FIND
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
ADD BEFORE
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function($) {
      if ($('input[name="shipping_method"]').length == 1) {
        $('input[name="shipping_method"]').trigger('click');
      }
    });
    //]]>
  </script>
SAVE&CLOSE
```

If the file doesn't exist in / you can copy it from it's parent... eventually that is app/design/frontend/base/default//template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml

thx for your help @Lapidi

Comment: .. But isn't this what the `$_sole` variable is for in `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`? The question is 'how to check it if it's available', not 'how to check it if it's the only one available'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following :

1) Go to your `template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`, inside foreach, check if current foreach item is `free_shipping`, add `checked="checked"` for that

Answer (score 1):

What about hiding other shipping if free shipping is active? And when you have only one Shipping Method or Payment Method, it will be auto selected by Magento.

**Rewrite the Block Class**

File: app/code/local/MagePsycho/Shipmentfilter/etc/config.xml

Code:

```
...
<blocks>
    ...
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <onepage_shipping_method_available>MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
    ...
</blocks>
...
```

**Override the getShippingRates() Method**

File: app/code/local/MagePsycho/Shipmentfilter/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter
 * @author     magepsycho@gmail.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        $rates = parent::getShippingRates();
        if (array_key_exists('freeshipping', $rates)) {
            $rates = array('freeshipping' => $rates['freeshipping']);
        }

        return $rates;
    }
}
```

This result will hide other shipping methods if free shipping is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

- Make sure that the 'free shipping' method is the only one available. Code in the template makes it automatically selected if it's the only one available.
- Look at `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` and change the code in a way that a rate will be checked if its code is 'freeshipping': change `<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>` to `<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod() || (!$this->getAddressShippingMethod() && $_rate->getCode() == 'freeshipping')) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>` *(disclaimer: I didn't actually try this, but the idea should be clear)*